# Mario CS-50 Dots

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int height; // Declare height
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height: "); //Ask user for height
    }
    while (height < 1 || height > 8); // This makes condition false so loop is not run any more and we can move on.

    for (int lines = 0; lines < height; lines++) //Correct
    {
        for (int hashes = -1; hashes < lines; hashes++) //Seems correct
        {
            for (int dots = lines - hashes; dots < 0; dots--) // Seems to do nothing....
            {
                  printf("."); //Prints "."
            }
            printf("#"); // Prints "# "
        }
        printf("\n"); // Prints New line
    }
}
```

As is, this just prints the incorrect-facing pyramid with no dots. I have ran some lines which include dots, but they have been space in between the "#'s" each time. I feel like dots + hashes has to equal the number of lines but I don't know how I would go about getting that in a "for" line.

Comment: Your dot loop is 'for (int dots = lines - hashes; dots < 0; dots--)' The loop as long as dots < 0. However, dots starts as a positive integer since lines > hashes, so this loop exits immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is it possible to solve the problem by getting this line fixed up or will I have trouble elsewhere?

Comment: I have no idea. You didn't describe the problem you're trying to solve. I just noticed that the loop wasn't what you were trying to do.

Comment: In addition to what @NomadMaker said, there is a bad design decision in your code. Nested for loops (last two) will print hashes and points back to back. Instead you should make separate (not nested) for loops to print hashes and points. Secondly, I know what is Mario pset from CS50 but most people in SO will not know about it. Please describe the problem better that you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 4;
    char blocks[n];
    char dots[n];
    memset(blocks,'#',n);
    memset(dots,  '.',n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.*s%.*s%.2s%.*s%.*s\n", n-i-1, dots,
                                         i+1,   blocks,
                                                dots,
                                         i+1,   blocks,
                                         n-i-1, dots);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4388KB
...#..#...
..##..##..
.###..###.
####..####
```